# Is there a way with resharper to change the color of a word or words of my specification?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way with resharper to change the color of a word or words of my specification?

In researching this, I found answers that recommended "Viasfora", but I am not able to get those suggestions to work. (Use the 'Visibility' list to specify my words)  When I add my own words to Visibility in Viasfora, they don't seem to be recognized.  Not sure if this is due to some other plugin, or what, but that solution is not working.

I have not been able to verify that there is any way in resharper to specify my own list of words.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's dedicated functionality in ReSharper for this task. You're probably better off using a dedicated plugin, e.g. [Word Highlight With Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungKienPhan.WordHighlight-18439).

The closest feature in ReSharper is To-Dos support. You can create a new pattern on the "To-do Explorer" settings page and configure it to match in comments, strings, and identifiers.